# Does it work? Ryzen 1800x and XFX RX590 on 4.15.0-46-generic?

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu, amd-graphics

I'm thinking on buying a Ryzen 1800x together with a XFX RX590.
I've been doing some reading but couldn't get my mind clear so I thought about asking someone with actual experience on these hardware.
So the question is simple: Does anybody knows if the actual kernel supports this configuration?
My current Kernel is 4.15.0-46-generic.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for recommendation/opinion on certain hardware components.

Comment: That's wrong! My idea was to know if the hardware mentioned above was supported by the actual kernel. I read that a lot of people had problems running this configuration. There are apparently some fixes but they are, as I understand, a little complex to perform.
I wasn't asking about opinions nor recommendations on hardware...

Comment: These things typically work without any major problem. If your question doesn't get a reopen, give a try to https://hardwarerecs.stackechange.com .